# Caliburn.Micro does not update ListView after dictationary changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro to build desktop MVVM application but have trouble with updating ListView.

This is my model:

```
 public class Answer
    {
        public int AnswerType { get; set; }
        public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestCaseConfig
    {
        public float MaxReactionTime { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }
```

and I'm using ObservableDictionary to notify view that collection has been changed (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/)

```
public ObservableDictionary<string, TestCaseConfig> testCaseConfigs { get; set; }
```

but when I update (add or delete item in `List<Answer> Answers`) my view does nothing

I've figure out that this issue caused because when we change something in collection also changes address in memory for it, but Caliburn don't react to this changes and continue to show previous list.

This is my view.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Gillie.Barney.Views.ExaminationAnswerSetupView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:localization="clr-namespace:Gillie.Barney.Properties"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Stretch" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView 
            Name="BaseListView"
            Margin="10" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding testCaseConfigs}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            SelectedItem ="{Binding TestCasesConfigSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn 
                        Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.TestCaseNameLable}" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Reaction Time">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value.MaxReactionTime}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Correct Answers">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ListView 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Value.Answers, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                        Grid.Column="0">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ComboBox 
                                                        Grid.Column="0" 
                                                        SelectedIndex="{Binding AnswerType}" 
                                                        Margin="5,0,5,0">
                                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static localization:Resources.ScriptsLabel}"/>
                                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static localization:Resources.AllObjectionsLabel}"/>
                                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Static localization:Resources.QuickAnswersLabel}"/>
                                                    </ComboBox>
                                                    <TextBox 
                                                        Grid.Column="1" 
                                                        Text="{Binding CorrectAnswer}"/>
                                                    <Button 
                                                        Grid.Column="2" 
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Width="20" 
                                                        Height="20" 
                                                        Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                                        cal:Message.Attach="DeleteItem($dataContext)">
                                                        <Button.Content>
                                                            <Image Source="/Resources/delete.ico"/>
                                                        </Button.Content>
                                                    </Button>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                    <Button 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                        Width="20" Height="20" 
                                        Grid.Column="1" 
                                        Margin="5,0,0,2"
                                        cal:Message.Attach="AddItem()">
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Image Source="/Resources/add.ico"/>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button 
            Content="{x:Static localization:Resources.SettingsSaveButtonContent}" 
            Margin="10,0,10,10" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            Grid.Column="1"
            cal:Message.Attach="Save()"/>
        <Button 
            Content="{x:Static localization:Resources.CancelButtonContent}" 
            Margin="10,0,10,10" 
            Grid.Row="2"  
            Grid.Column="0"
            cal:Message.Attach="Cancel()"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since i've used caliburn micro,  so take the following with a grain of salt :)

```
ObservableDictionary<string, TestCaseConfig>
```

Only listens for changes directly on the dictionary, meaning when you add or remove an item to the dictionary. In your case, you don't do that, but rather, you change something in an item already in the dictionary.

So, what you need is to change your

```
public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
```

to a list that can be observed on - such as `ObservableList<Anwer>`  (Or a similar name - can't remember the Caliburn.Micro terminology).

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!